# kernel of $R\to R/(f)$ is non zero

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R = \Bbb{Z}/(6)$ be the base ring,define polynomial ring $R[x]$ over it.

Let $f = 2x+1$ , $(2x+1)$ be the ideal generated by $f$ then if we restrict the canonical map $\pi :R[x] \to R[x]/(2x+1)$ to $\nu:R\to R[x]/(2x+1)$, prove the kernel is non-zero.

I try to prove $3 \in R$ is the desired one, but I don't know what does $\Bbb{Z}/(6)$ mean? Is it $\Bbb{Z}_6$?

Comment: I guess so. The official notation is $\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$. $(6)$ denotes the ideal generated by $6$.

Comment: Thanks I got it since $6x + 3 = 3$ in $\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$ then

Comment: @yili More conceptually $2$ is a unit in the quotient $(2(-x) = 1)$ so $\,2\cdot 3 = 0\Rightarrow 3 = 0\,$ by cacelling the unit $2$ (by scaling by its inverse). $\ \ $

Comment: thanks @Bill Dubuque  I make your statement more formal,since $2\cdot 3 = 0$ in ring $R\subset R[x]$ hence ring homomorphism $\pi(2\cdot 3) = \pi(2)\cdot\pi(3) = 0$ now $\pi(2)\dot\pi(-x) = \pi(1)$ hence multipling $\pi(-x)$ on both side of $\pi(2\cdot 3) = \pi(2)\cdot\pi(3) = 0$ gives the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical map is given by $\pi:f(x)\mapsto f(x)+ \langle 2x+1\rangle$.

The restriction is then $\nu: z \mapsto z+\langle 2x+1\rangle$.

The ideal $\langle 2x+1\rangle $ contains $2(2x+1) = 4x+2$, $3(2x+1) = 6x+3= 3$, $4(2x+1) = 8x+4= 2x+3$, $5(2x+1) = 10x+5= 4x+5$.

It follows that $3\in \langle 2x+1\rangle$ and so $3\in\ker\nu$.

Comment: $3 = 3(2x+1)$ hence $3 \in \left<2x+1\right>$? @Wuestenfux